# How does a fighter get his 4th attack per round in Labyrinth Lord?

Tags: labyrinth-lord

The Labyrinth Lord rules, p11, say:

> Beginning at 15th level, a fighter gains one additional attack per round. One further attack is gained every 5 levels to a maximum of 4 attacks per round.

So, I expect that he has two at 15th, three at 20th, and four at 25th.

Fighter progression is not specified beyond level 20, and I don't see any supplement that would detail it.  The relevant rules in B/X D&D were found on page X8 of the D&D Expert Rules, specifying simple rules for each class's progression beyond 14th level, but no such chart is given for Labyrinth Lord.

Is there an in-book rule for this that I haven't found, or do those few campaigns reaching this question just fall back to Cook's Expert Rules?

Comment: Since it's supposed to be a proper clone, I suspect that's an unintentional omission.

Comment: I think that might be the case, too but (a) they did change the class progressions to go to 20 instead of 14 and (b) I'm surprised this omission would survive to the revised edition, if it's a mistake.  I am only an amateur nit-picker, and I found it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note: Labyrinth Lord is not a true Retroclone. It's a really close pseudoclone, but has mixed and matched bits from both Moldvay/Cook and Mentzer D&D. The progressions, however, of several items do not match Moldvay basic, Cook Expert, nor Mentzer Basic/Expert/Companion, namely: save tables, to hit tables, thief skills table.

Few games actually give details past level 20. Generally, tho', one can extrapolate the progressions.

Note that all save tables for humans end where shown; Cleric and Thief at 17+, Fighter and MU 19+, and the To Hits end at the 19+ level line for fighters, the 21+ line for Clerics and Theives, and 24+ for MU, but could easily be extended if you feel it worth doing. Clerical progression on turning caps at 14th level. Cleric and MU spell tables cap at 20th level; the cleric does not match Moldvay, Cook, nor Mentzer. Thief skills also cap at 14th level, save for the bonus of 5% per 5 levels difference in level.

The fighter above 20th is +120,000XP, +2 HP, and the bonus attacks to level 25; no further gains of to hit nor saves.

So, extending the table:

```
1,560,001  20   +22 hp only   3 attacks per round
1,680,001  21   +24 hp only
1,800,001  22   +26 hp only
1,920,001  23   +28 hp only
2,040,001  24   +30 hp only
2,160,001  25   +32 hp only   4 attacks per round (maximum)
```

Clerics are +100,000xp, +1hp, max out their to hit at 21st level, and no other gains per level, aside from ability to ignore certain spells of lower level casters.

Thieves are also 120,000xp per level past 20, +2 hp each level, and no gains in to hit past 21st level.

Magic Users are 150,000xp per level past 20th, +1 HP per level, no gains in to hit past 24th level, no gains to saves.

Comment: This seems like the simplest way to interpret the rules.  I hope they'll make it clearer in the next edition, but... you know, I never expect to see PCs make it far enough to matter...

Answer (score 3):

If you look carefully you'll notice that after 10th level the four human classes all have the same increase in XP between levels that they did from 9th to 10th.  In fact it starts after 8th for clerics and 9th for fighters and magic-users.  For example fighters:

8: 120,001xp
9: 240,001xp
10: 360,001xp

that increase of 120,000xp per level continues to level 20.  Just extrapolate that as levels increase.